# sharepoint 2007 search crawl

Tags: sharepoint-2007

My Problem is:
I have sharepoint 2007 web application and windows server 2008 OS.
I was doing search in sharepoint 2007 and it was working fine.
Recently I've added a new website page but it didn't appear in the search result.
I also looked up for it in the crawl log but I didn't find the page url.

[NEW INFO]
when I switched to windows authentication everything was fine and the page was found in the search process.but switching back to form authentication will not make the webpage appear in the search result.

My Question is: how can I make the new page appear in the search result?

Answer (score 0):

Newly created page is not available in serach results until the Full Crawl or Incremental Crawl is complete..

Did u perform the crawl after you have created the page ?

Comment: Yes of course I performed incremental crawl.
However I noticed that switching the authentication back to windows will make the crawler find the page.but switching the crawler back to form authentication will not make it find the page after crawling ofcourse.

So, something wrong with form authentication.

unfortunatelly I have to use form authentication ....

So is that clear enough for help?

Comment: Chek user policy for the WEb application in CA ,The Search crawling account must be have full read access too.

Comment: Ialso set the default content access account to be the administrator of the domain and I set the farm search service account to the network service and add network service to the administrator group in AD.

Comment: I uninstall the microsoft office server 2007 and insatll windows sharepoint services 2007 with sp3,now I don't have options for managing search service but the same problem appears with form authentication.and the problem disappear with windows authentication.

Comment: I cant find any clue for your problem

Comment: dear SigarDave according to micrsofot article on the following url http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934577#appliesto I can guess that I am facing no problem. search is a built in feature for windows authentication and not for form authentication

Comment: Ohh okay thanks for that link.Learning is always a continiuos process. Thanks again.Provide answer for your own question so that other people can also get help for these issue in future